# Select all from the left table in a many to many relationship and display its associations

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables in a `many to many relationship`.

```
Table Properties

id  title

1   exampleTitle
2   exampleTitle2
3   exampleTitle3
-------------------------------------------

Table Adverts

id  title           type

1   exampleTitle    tv
2   exampleTitle2   radio
3   exampleTitle3   magazine
--------------------------------------------

Table AdvertsToProperties

property_id     advert_id

1               1
1               2
3               3
--------------------------------------------
```

What i want to do, is to `select *` from the table *Properties* with all the associated *Adverts*. I have already tried to reach that by using `LEFT JOIN` but i got back duplicate rows from the *Properties* table. I need a way to get each row from the table *Properties* **once** and the it's adverts.

**UPDATE:**

I have a an `HTML` view that displays all the properties. Every property is inside a `div` that has an `HTML` table which shows the property's adverts. I want to display the property's div only once. Can i reach that without making a second `query` for the adverts of each property?

Comment: If it has multiple adverts it must have multiple rows; unless you `GROUP BY Properties.id`, in which case you will only get one advert for each property.

Comment: @Uueerdo Exactly. That is what i want to avoid. I need a way to get the adverts separately.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want the outcome to look like?  How do you want to tell that the advert is associated with the property if you don't want the property info duplicated for each association?

Comment: Agree with @aphrael also if he would create http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be nice so we can play with that

Comment: I thought that to show us desired output of query as you show us table you have...